# Call a child method from parent component using reference variable as dynamic

Tags: angular, typescript

Parent component html.

**selectedTab** is dynamically changed as 0,1,2,3.

```
<div fxFlex="50%" class="back_link refresh_icon" (click)="index_[selectedTab].refreshData(activatedRouteSnapshot)">
        </div>
    
    <app-child1 #index_2></app-child1>
    <app-child2 #index_3></app-child2>
```

I have a method in child2 .ts

```
 refreshData(test){
        console.log(test)
      }
```

I am getting the below issue.

Cannot read property '3' of undefined

Comment: Error means `selectedTab.RefreshData` is not a function. First console log the variable and check what are you getting in `selectedTab` then you can probably find valid error

Comment: i am getting 3 in selectedTab.

Comment: Maybe show us your selectedTab? Is that object or function?

Comment: So your selectedTab is just a number `(click)="selectedTab.refreshData(activatedRouteSnapshot)">` is causing error as you are trying to call a function `refreshData` on selectedTab

Comment: it is a variable selectedTab = 3;

Comment: yes @pavankumar

Comment: Am taking a wild shot here, I am guessing you have a function called `refreshData` in your component so try to do `(click)="refreshData(activatedRouteSnapshot)">` instead of what you are trying

Comment: Have some parent component  method and from that method emit an event, then subscribe it from your child component

Comment: no @ArunKumar its a lengthy process, do you have any idea, how to call  method.
(click)="selectedTab.refreshData(activatedRouteSnapshot)"

Comment: you should do this = > `(click)="1.refreshData(activatedRouteSnapshot)"`

Comment: @micronyks u r right but i need to do it dynamically.

Comment: I don't think it will be possible with template ref variable....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Observer in place of reference variable.

parent component.ts

```
selectedTabSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject();
onRefreshChild(activatedRouteSnapshot) {
    this.selectedTabSubject.next({ id: activatedRouteSnapshot, index: this.selectedTab });
  }
```

In parent html

```
<app-charging-ports [selectedIndex]="selectedTabSubject"></app-charging-ports>
```

In child.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.selectedIndex.subscribe(value => { 
          console.log('value is changing', value);
       });
      }
@Input() selectedIndex: Subject<any>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `@ViewChildren` + a function in the parent that you call on click.

Something along the lines

```
// Parent component

@ViewChildren(child2) tabs: QueryList<child2>;   <= put the actual class name of that child component

onRefreshChild(selectedTab, activatedRouteSnapshot) {
  tabs[selectedTab].refreshData(activatedRouteSnapshot);
}
```

In the html:

```
<div fxFlex="50%" class="back_link refresh_icon" (click)="onRefreshChild(selectedTab, activatedRouteSnapshot)">
</div>
```

If you have `selectedTab` as a property in the parent component, you of course don't need to pass it, just use `this.selectedTab` in `onRefreshChild`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I need to this dynamically because i have more than 8 child component.

Comment: This is dynamic. ViewChildren will always update when there are changes to the view (e.g. a tab is added or removed).

Comment: In this i have to import all child in parent.

Comment: In that case I would recommend to create a base class the child components extend and then go along this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8580